# Lint for android in Eclipse gives wrong results

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

If I run "lint ." inside project directory I get the expected warnings, but if I run it from inside eclipse I get nonsense errors and warnings, for example:

- The resource R.array.settings_derivatives appears to be unused [in fact, it is used]
- The  x.y.z is not registered in the manifest [in fact, it is registered]
- Call requires API level 3 (current min is 1): android.view.SurfaceView#isInEditMode [in fact minSdkVersion is set to 7]

**edit:** If I create a new workspace and import the existing projects I get the right errors

Comment: [Call requires API level 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isInEditMode%28%29) is true. It't not about your target level but about the "since API 3" where that method was introduced. You can probably turn that warning off - it only makes sense if you want to port your app to a lower min level that you currently have

Comment: It's true, but it should not be reported, as I've set the minSdkVersion to 7. And it's not reported as a warning, rather, as an error...
And my point is that the command line tool gives a different [correct] result

Comment: First, make sure you are on the latest tools (R17) and the corresponding Eclipse plugin. If the problems persist, then create a sample project that reproduces the problem, then submit a bug report to http://b.android.com. I have not seen those particular messages occur before.

Comment: Latest tools and Eclipse plugin. Will try and reproduce on a smaller project

Comment: You are right - I misinterpreted that error / purpose of the check. Try `Project > Clean..`, that may help resolve issues. Btw: I have no warning on `isInEditMode`. These warning / error checkers get often confused if there is another error in your project like illegal xml syntax in your manifest.

Comment: Clean didn't solve, and no illegal xml. Although I do have a rather messy setup: Android project depends on android library depends on j2me project depends on another j2me project, so it wouldn't suprise me THAT much if it gets confused

Comment: I tried reproducing on a new project and coulnd't. I'm now trying to strip the actual project to barebone to see what's wrong

Comment: Switching workspace and importing the old projects caused the warnings to change. I guess it's probably some issue with stale files in my workspace

Comment: I have the same problem, you can follow the issue status [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27527)

Comment: Summary of Rick's link:  A fix has been made and will be included in tools r20.

Comment: @miniBill, After the bug fix, does the problem still persists?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't use Eclipse anymore, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be an issue, when the project directory is not directly under the workspace directory.

As of today the bug should be fixed in release 20:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27527

Edit:

If necessary you can make a softlink into the workspace.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved by switching workspace to a fresh one. It probably was a problem with settings left over from previous lint versions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using this:-

Right click on the project folder > Android tools > Clear Link Markers

"Run Android Lint" makes some markers and the markers cause this error.

Answer (score -1):

"Preference --> Android --> Lint Error Checking", search issues "NewApi", and you can see the settings.

> This check scans through all the Android API calls in the application and warns about any calls that are not available on *all* versions targeted by this application (according to its minimum SDK attribute in the manifest).
>
> If your code is *deliberately* accessing newer APIs, and you have ensured (e.g. with conditional execution) that this code will only ever be called on a supported platform, then you can annotate your class or method with the @TargetApi

Comment: I know what the warning means. The point is that the warning should not be there!