# Android studio : call requires API Level 16 error

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the following error in Android studio. The `sqlitedatabase.close()` method is available since API Level 1 but the android studio ide fails to detect that.

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Heh. It's still an early preview (version 0.1), so it could just be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of days ago, an updated version appeared (build AI-130.687321, dated May 24 2013), where the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmad said, it looks like a bug. Meanwhile, try `releaseReference()` which is [equivalent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html#releaseReference%28%29) to see if the same happens.

UPDATE:

Supposing you were in Eclipse, to re-enable checks (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069936/how-to-re-enable-a-disabled-android-lint-warning-on-file-level)):

Lint puts the file "lint.xml" to the project with the dependant items.

```
<lint>
  <issue id="UnusedResources">
    <ignore path="res\layout\my_layout.xml" />
  </issue>
<lint>
```

Unfortunatelly, editing and saving this file is not enough. You have to close and re-open the project or even Eclipse.

Not sure if Android Studio does the same.

UPDATE 2:

In Android Studio, you can see all the Lint based inspections and tune them in 'Settings | Inspections | Android | Lint'.

Or you could use the command line tool in the SDK tools/ directory called lint.

Comment: I disabled the checks for that class. Do you know how I can re-enable it?

Comment: Did you disable them with 'lint --disable'? If so, use 'lint --enable'.

Comment: releaseReference() doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851377/lint-for-android-in-eclipse-gives-wrong-results):

There seems to be an issue, when the project directory is not directly under the workspace directory.

As of today the bug should be fixed in release 20: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27527

In that case, the problem was solved by switching workspace to a fresh one. It probably was a problem with settings left over from previous lint versions